# How to completely hide typed characters in a Flutter TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield, flutter-textinputfield

In my Flutter app, I use a `TextFormField`, so my users can enter a password.

In order to hide the characters while they are being typed, I set the `obscureText` property to `true`. But on some devices, when I type a character, that character is visible for a second or so.

Even though I know it's a very common behavior, is it possible to completely hide the character while it is being typed, and show only the *obscuring character* instead, aside from using a special font only made of dots?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `TextEditingController` and override its `buildTextSpan` to create your own obscuring `TextField`:

```dart
class ObscuringTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({required BuildContext context, TextStyle? style, required bool withComposing}) {
    return TextSpan(text: '•' * value.text.length, style: style); // Consider using a more performant way to build string, such as StringBuffer
  }
}
```

Please note that this is only a minimal implementation for sample purpose. You might need to be aware of other aspects from the original `buildTextSpan` method that may need to be implemented as well in the overriding method.

---

This answer is a modified version of my answer on another question (with a different goal): https://stackoverflow.com/a/77791236/13625293

Comment: Thanks! Also, to make sure it's working, I had to set obscureText to false.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is depending on which system you run your Flutter application. If you run it in the web for example, you will see that it hides all characters:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

On Android it checks the system settings to show the last character.

Look in your Android settings for "Make password visible" and disable it.